# how to make a condition in java with sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I want to make a condition if the first name and the last name are in the database the score will be updated, else the data will be inserted normally as a new user.

My code:

```
public void data(View view)
{  
    scor=String.valueOf(qc1.scor);
    db.execSQL("UPDATE Student SET email='"+scor+"' WHERE fname ='"+exo.fname+"' AND lname ='"+exo.lname+"';");
     Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "data updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
     toast.show();
}
```

Comment: what output u getting now?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select 1 from Student where fname=? AND lname =?", 
         new String[] { exo.fname, exo.lname });
    if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        // this means we found at least one entry that matches the name
        // update database here
    } else {
        // otherwise that user doesn't exist yet
        // insert into database here
    }
```

Comment: thanks man it really works , but i don't know why it did not worked before. you are the best <3.

Answer (score 0):

this may help you

```
  ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
  cv.put(columnName,columnValue);
  long x = sqLiteDatabase.update(TableName,cv,columnName1 " = ? and "+columnName2+" = ? ",new String[]{coulmn1Val,column2val});
  if(x<=0){

    // insert data because no any record is updated 
    //insert statement here
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [insertWithOnConflict](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertWithOnConflict%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20int%29) with a conflictAlgorithm [CONFLICT_REPLACE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#CONFLICT_REPLACE) if you have a unique constraint

> When a UNIQUE constraint violation occurs...the insert or update always occurs

Comment: This is probably the best solution if fname and lname are the primary key (or have an unique constraint).

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this problem in a few different ways:

1. Check if the row exists (with `query()`). If it does, then insert, else, update.
2. Try to update. If no records were updated, then insert.

I would recommend approach 2, since it may save you one statement execution (especially if updates are common). For example:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("email", scor);
if (db.update("Student", values, "fname = ? AND lname = ?", new String[] { exo.fname, exo.lname }) == 0)
{
    // Not an update. Insert
    values.put("fname", exo.fname);
    values.put("lname", exo.lname);
    db.insert("Student", null, values);
}
```

Comment: i did't knew you can do this , thanks bro this will help me a lot